# Proper way to send result of a T-SQL query to a file

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I already know, in a T-SQL stored procedure, how to create a file via a `bcp` command called using `xp_cmdshell`. Basic example:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(4000)
SET @cmd='bcp "SELECT * FROM myTable FOR XML RAW" queryout D:\myFile.xml -c -T'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Now my problem is: in my case, the query is very long, with lots of nested queries. Yes it fits in a varchar, but writing it as a string in quotes makes it unmaintanable. And the result of the query is thousands of lines long so it doesn't fit in a varchar.

Is there a way where I could write my query in plain T-SQL and then send the result to my bcp command without having to put neither the query, nor its result, in a varchar?

I know that SSIS packages could be a solution, but I would like to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: If you're happy with @Pepto's answer, please mark their answer as accepted (and also consider upvoting it). Votes and Accepts are how we know that questions have been answered, not edits to your question.

Comment: As a matter of fact, his main answer was not the solution, it's just something he commented after that gave me the right idea.

Comment: In that case, if you have a satisfactory answer now, please post it **as** an answer. After a delay, you'll be able to mark that answer as your accepted answer.

Comment: I thought about letting him modify his answer and then mark it as accepted, or creating another answer if he doesn't do anything today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: as suggested by Pepto, bcp can execute a stored procedure instead of a SELECT.

So :

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(200)
SET @cmd='bcp "execute MyDb.dbo.MySP" queryout D:\myFile.xml -c -T'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Where `MySP` is a stored procedure containing my huge SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered (sorry can't tell from question) to write your output into a Temp Table using those same queries within a Stored Procedure, and then using bcp to copy the output of that Temp Table before dropping it?

I've done this many times and works like a charm. But may not be applicable here.

Comment: I did. In fact, the complexity of my query doesn't come from the number of tables I select from, but from the very specific XML format I use as an output, so I can't do much about it...

Comment: Sadly I can't think of a way to break it out different sorry =(

Comment: Would making your query syntax into a function work? SET @cmd='bcp ' + myfunction() + ' queryout D:\myFile.xml -c -T'? Just slinging mud here

Comment: Mmh it might. Depends on what bcp accepts as a parameter. If I can just call a function/stored procedure from within the bcp command, the aforesaid function/SP might just contain my plain SQL... I'll dig into that and come back later with the result. Thanks!

Comment: Well after all @cmd is just a variable of varchar (string). If the function returned the "query syntax" then it would work for sure. If you are looking to write the SQL Statements themselves without quotation marks and concatenation etc I think using a Temp Table is the only option besides SSIS. Again, more mud =P happy coding

Comment: 2 months later.... It worked! I updated my original message to detail the solution. Thanks a lot.